# MongoDB: Get all mentioned items

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've got two relations in my Mongoose/MongoDB-Application:

USER:

```
{
   name: String,
   items: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Spot' }]
}
```

and
ITEM

```
{
   title: String,
   price: Number
}
```

As you can see, my user-collection containing a "has-many"-relation to the item-collection.

I'm wondering how to get all Items which are mentioned in the items-field of on specific user.

Guess its very common question, but I haven't found any solution on my own in the Docs or elsewhere. Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are Storing items reference in user collection,then fetch all items from user,it will give you a array of object ids of items and then you can access all items bases on their ids

```
var itemIdsArray = User.items;

    Item.find({
        '_id': { $in: itemIdsArray}
    }, function(err, docs){
         console.log(docs);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the items at the same time you query for the user, by using Mongoose's support for [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html):

```js
User.findOne({_id: userId}).populate('items').exec(function(err, user) {
    // user.items contains the referenced docs instead of just the ObjectIds    
});
```